# Adjust amount of spacing between Vaadin widgets

Tags: java, vaadin, vaadin7

## Vaadin Spacing

[Vaadin](https://www.Vaadin.com/) layouts have a method `setSpacing( true )` that moves widgets apart from one another. Works well in most cases. But in the case of multiple Table objects, they are still a bit too crowded.

> ➜ Is there some way to increase the amount of spacing used in a particular layout?

## CSS

I expect the answer to be a tweak to CSS. In the [Book of Vaadin](https://vaadin.com/book) page on [Layout Formatting](https://vaadin.com/book/-/page/layout.settings.html), the last section *Layout Margins* discusses CSS for margins. But I cannot find discussion of CSS for spacing.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can increase the spacing between Vaadin components/widgets. How you do so depends on the particular kind of layout. So see the documentation for each kind of layout.

For [`HorizontalLayout` and `VerticalLayout`](https://vaadin.com/book/-/page/layout.orderedlayout.html), use the `.v-spacing` selector with a `height` or `width` rule.

### `VerticalLayout` (and `FormLayout`)

```
.v-vertical > .v-spacing {
    height: 30px;
}
```

### `HorizontalLayout`

```
.v-horizontal > .v-spacing {
    width: 50px;
}
```

Comment: ☹  I took that answer from the Vaadin doc. But it is not working for me. If anyone can add more, please do.

Comment: It works for me. Maybe another CSS rule overrides it in your case.

Answer (score 0):

in your compiled css file:

```
.YourThemeName.v-app .v-vertical > .v-spacing {
    height: 30px;
}
```

Comment: Is there something special about the spacing rule that requires the theme name and app selector? I do not need this on other rules in my Vaadin 7.3 app, where I write rules in the `mytheme.scss` file created by the Vaadin plugin 1.1.1 for NetBeans 8. I have rules as simple as: `.example-gridlayout { border: medium dotted greenyellow; }`